# How to minimize the distance between two curves in 3D

Tags: graphics3d

I'm trying to find the shortest distance between r(t) and rm(t), at a certain time t. I could not get it using EuclideanDistance, any guess on how to do that?
Here is what I have:

```
r[t_] = {Sin[2 \[Pi]*t], t^3, Cos[2 \[Pi]*t]^2};
EscapePath = 
  ParametricPlot3D [ r[t], {t, 0, 2}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Large], Style["y", Large ], 
     Style["z", Large]}];
start = Graphics3D[{Green, Sphere[r[0], 0.1]}];
loc1 = Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere [r[2], 0.1]}];

rm[t_] = {1.2*Sin[2 \[Pi]*t], t^4, 1.1*Cos[2 \[Pi]*(t + 0.2)]^2};
MissilePath = 
  ParametricPlot3D [ rm[t], {t, 0, 2}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Large], Style["y", Large ], 
     Style["z", Large]}];
startm = Graphics3D[{Blue, Sphere[rm[0], 0.1]}];
loc1m = Graphics3D[{Yellow, Sphere [rm[2], 0.1]}];

Show[EscapePath, MissilePath, start, startm, loc1, loc1m, 
 PlotRange -> All, Background -> RGBColor[0.97`, 0.93`, 0.68`] ]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
r[t_] = {Sin[2 \[Pi]*t], t^3, Cos[2 \[Pi]*t]^2};

rm[t_] =
  {1.2*Sin[2 \[Pi]*t], t^4, 1.1*Cos[2 \[Pi]*(t + 0.2)]^2} //
   Rationalize;

separation[t_] = 
  EuclideanDistance[r[t], rm[t]] //
   Simplify[#, Element[t, Reals]] &;

separation[t] == Norm[r[t] - rm[t]] //
 Simplify[#, Element[t, Reals]] &
```

> True

```
minPts = {#[[2, 1, -1]], #[[1]]} & /@
   (FindMinimum[
       {separation[t], 
        0 <= t <= 2}, {t, #}] & /@
     {.15, .4, .65, .9, 1.15, 1.4});

Plot[separation[t], {t, 0, 1.5},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], 
   Tooltip[Point[#], #] & /@ minPts},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@
    {"t", "Separation"})]
```

[image]

```
NMinimize[{separation[t], 0 <= t <= 2}, t]
```

> {0.118657, {t -> 0.4059}}

Comment: Wow that is exactly what i was trying to achieve, thanks.
I was using the function EuclideanDistance wrong so thats why it wouldn't compute the distance.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum of distance is achieved at the same point as the minimum of the square of the distance, so

```
Minimize[{, (r[t]-rm[t]).(r[t]-rm[t]), t>=0, t<=2}, {t}]
```

Should do the trick.