# Finding minimal distance between two surfaces

Tags: mathematical-optimization, topology

This code will display two parametric surfaces:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{
    {4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 4 + Sin[v]},
    {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 3 + Sin[v], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]}
  },
  {u, 0, 2 Pi},
  {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

How to find minimal distance between these surfaces? *(`u` and `v` do not need to be the same for both surfaces at the point of minimum; points can be chosen independently on two surfaces; in other words, geometric minimum is needed)*

I tried to setup `NMinimize[]`, but didn't get meaningful results.

This is inspired by a couple of similar recent questions ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60178/how-to-minimize-the-distance-between-two-curves-in-3d) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60809/finding-the-point-of-minimum-distance-between-two-parametric-functions)), I wanted to know how to apply similar techniques in different circumstances.

Naturally, I would like the method of the solution to be able to work on many other examples of two surfaces, this is just a fairly simple example... For example, if two surfaces intersect or touch, the method should return 0 as for minimal distance, etc... I appreciate your time and effort!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
eq1 = {4 + (3 + Cos[q]) Sin[p], 4 + Cos[p] (3 + Cos[q]), 4 + Sin[q]};
eq2 = {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 3 + Sin[v], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]};
nm  = NMinimize[EuclideanDistance[eq1, eq2], {u, v, p, q}]

(* {2.20785*10^-8, {u -> 2.7672, v -> 3.04956, p -> 1.97302,  q -> 2.31892}} *)
```

In fact they intersect:

```
{x0, y0, z0} = eq1 /. nm[[2]];
Show[ParametricPlot3D[eq1, {p, 0, 2 Pi}, {q, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
                      RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#1, #2, #3} - {x0, y0, z0}] < 2 &)], 
     ParametricPlot3D[eq2, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Green]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! I assume that 6.13246*10^-8 means that the surfaces actually touch each other - i am little confused why NMinimize didn't return something closer to 0 or exact 0...

Comment: @Adrian yep, they intersect. See the plot.

Answer (score 5):

If these tori didn't intersect then  we would be able to estimate the minimal distance between them with `NMinimize`, however this is not the case here although the plot in the question makes some kind of confusion. Nevertheless we can prove that they actually intersect with a kind of **topological reasoning** based on [homotopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy) equivalence.

We define parametrizations of each tori:

```
torus1[u_, v_] := {4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 4 + Sin[v]} 
torus2[u_, v_] := {8 + (3 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], 3 + Sin[v], 4 + (3 + Cos[v]) Sin[u]}
```

### Continuity Argument

If the both tori were **disjoint being entangled** then all plane sections parallel to the big circles of the tori would be **entangled** too, otherwise **there must exist certain sections of the tori which are not entangled**. Here we provide  clear examples of such sections:

```
   GraphicsRow[ 
     ParametricPlot3D[{ torus1[u1, #1], torus2[u1, #2]}, { u1, 0, 2 π}, 
         PlotStyle -> {{ Thickness[0.01], Darker @ Green}, 
                       { Thickness[0.01], Red}}, 
         ViewPoint -> #3, PlotLabel -> #4]& @@@ {
       { π, 3 π/2, {16, 4, 6}, "Unentangled"}, 
       { π/2, 3 π/2, {6, 4, 6}, "Entangled"}}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

In fact this argument is **a straightforward proof that the distance of the tori is zero** since these two sections are homotopically equivalent thus there must exist a parameter when the both sections intersect.

Working with `NMinimize` we can estimate reliably an upper bound for the minimum  when the both tori are disjoint, however if they are not then  `NMinimize` will only suggest it yielding a very small number such as below.

We can use `NMinimize` with `Norm`:

```
NMinimize[ Join[ { Norm[torus1[u1, v1] - torus2[u2, v2]], 
                  Thread[0 <= # <= 2 π &[{u1, v1, u2, v2}]]}],
          {u1, v1, u2, v2}]
```

or with  `EuclideanDistance`:

```
NMinimize[ Join[{ EuclideanDistance[ torus1[u1, v1], torus2[u2, v2]], 
                  Thread[0 <= # <= 2 π &[{u1, v1, u2, v2}]]}],
           {u1, v1, u2, v2}]
```

> ```
> {1.30702*10^-7, {u1 -> 2.43975, v1 -> 4.16231, u2 -> 3.48281, v2 -> 4.24283}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Artes. I believe, at the first sight, that your solution assumes that u and v are the same on both surfaces. However, I removed that condition in the statement, so the result should be different. However, +1 anyway! Please keep the answer, since it is useful, even if I am right in this comment.

Comment: @Adrian Now this is not only useful but mathematically correct reasoning unlike in the other answer.

Comment: Right, my first comment referred to the first version of your answer, where only u and v were used, but now u1, v1, u2, v2 are used, which is correct, so the comment is now obsolete, but the reader would understand that from the whole discussion.

Comment: @Artes this is a good exposition. Note however, that the "entanglement" depends on the embedding. It's pointless to talk about tori that are "entagled" unless embedded in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ much like it's pointless (no pun intended) to talk about a point being "inside" a circle unless you embed said point and circle in $ \mathbb{R} ^2. $

Comment: @gpap Thanks, I guess it it clear from the context however it would be more precise to use the term "entanglment" as a metaphore. Sometimes one has to use inaccurate terms expressing simple facts.