# Compactness and Connectedness of sets

Tags: topology

Can we check Compactness/Connectedness of sets in $R^{2}$ using some mathematica code ?

If Yes , Can anyone tell how ?

Comment: How are the sets going to be specified?  Mathematica has some functions such as `CylindricalDecomposition` that might help you, but they work primarily with inequalities in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: This question is very general and the answer is "of course, we can", if you are interested in a certain topological  technique related to the general problem see e.g. this anser [Finding minimal distance between two surfaces](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65847/finding-minimal-distance-between-two-surfaces/65848#65848)

Comment: Can you give a specify example to compute